# NodeJS, MSSQL Bulk Get and save weather observations from API

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server

I am trying to write a Nodejs file to loop through 700 weather reports from the Bureau Of Meteorology JSON file. Each file contains a number of weather observations from the past 24 hours for a particular weather site: air temp, gust_kmh etc. For each file I want to find the min/max/mean avg of each of the observations (air_temp_min, air_temp_max, air_temp_avg). Then I want to commit this to a MSSQL database. I'd plan on doing this once a day, so each location observation would be entered as a single line in the databases with multiple columns.

I am newish to async operations and I keep getting into trouble with linking one operation/function/promise to the next, or surpassing the max listeners.

So I need a suggestion or direction about how to do it, elegantly and effectively. I don't mind which packages are used, I've tries with request, axios, mssql, tedious. I can get all of them to work individually for one line, but not together in a harmonious way.

The starting point would be to iterate through the URLs for each of the sites. Here is a sample.

```
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95767.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95772.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94650.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95774.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95754.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95747.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95779.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94774.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94781.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95770.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95758.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.99738.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94775.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94776.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94773.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95773.json,
http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94588.json
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use the modules request (+request-promise-native), mssql and then lodash (for aggregations, e.g. max, min, average) and moment for date parsing. Here's some sample code that will do what you want.

You'll need to run the cmd line below to install dependencies:

```
npm install mssql request request-promise-native lodash moment --save
```

Now as regards scheduling the calls, I'd suggest maybe just setting up a scheduled task to call the script once a day (depending on your OS.)

Some ToDos.. maybe look at ensuring we're closing connections nicely etc and some exception handling in case something chokes!

After running this, I see the rows below in the db:

**Weather_data**

```
timestamp               |location_name                  |air_temp_max |air_temp_min |air_temp_avg
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Lake Macquarie - Cooranbong    |32.4         |17.8         |23.1027777777778
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Maitland Airport               |33.9         |19.9         |24.4478260869565
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Mangrove Mountain              |30           |18.1         |22.3784722222222
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Merriwa                        |34.8         |18.6         |25.4435897435898
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Murrurundi Gap                 |31.4         |17.4         |23.3627906976744
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Nelson Bay                     |26.4         |22.5         |24.7
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Newcastle Nobbys               |27.7         |21.1         |23.1243055555556
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Newcastle University           |26.8         |21.6         |24.2
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Norah Head                     |29.5         |20.6         |23.3048611111111
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Scone Airport                  |35.8         |20.4         |26.0236363636363
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Singleton (Defence)            |34.5         |20           |25.1141891891892
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Tocal                          |33.6         |20           |24.7993055555556
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Williamtown                    |31.5         |20.7         |23.6551724137931
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Armidale                       |20.7         |19.8         |20.3
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Armidale Airport               |29.7         |13.9         |22.0801282051282
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000 |Glen Innes Airport             |29.7         |15.1         |21.8228187919463
```

**Weather Schema SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE weather_data (
    timestamp datetime,
    location_name nvarchar(200),
    air_temp_max float,
    air_temp_min float,
    air_temp_avg float,
);
```

Node code:

**index.js**

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
const _ = require('lodash');
const sql = require('mssql');
const moment = require('moment');

const config = {
    user: 'db_user',  // Change as appropriate
    password: 'pass',  // Change as appropriate
    server: 'localhost', // Change as appropriate
    database: 'Weather',
    port: 1433 // Default port, change as appropriate
}

let sqlConnPool = null;

const urlList = [
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95767.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95772.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94650.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95774.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95754.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95747.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95779.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94774.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94781.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95770.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95758.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.99738.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94775.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94776.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94773.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95773.json',
    'http://reg.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.94588.json'
];

async function downloadStationData() {
    for(url of urlList)  {
        let res = await downloadAndSaveWeatherData(url);
        console.log("Res: ", res);
    }
}

sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    console.log("Connected to database...");
    sqlConnPool = pool;
    downloadStationData()
});

async function downloadAndSaveWeatherData(url) {
    console.log("downloadAndSaveWeatherData: Downloading from: ", url);
    let weatherData = await downloadWeatherData(url);
    if (weatherData.observations && weatherData.observations.data && weatherData.observations.data.length > 0) {
        console.log("downloadAndSaveWeatherData: Observations (count): ", weatherData.observations.data.length);
        let processedData = processWeatherData(weatherData.observations.data);
        console.log("downloadAndSaveWeatherData: processed data: ", processedData);
        let writeResult = await writeWeatherDataToDatabase(processedData);
        return { status: "OK"};
    }
}

// Get max, min, average etc.
function processWeatherData(data) {
    const result = { 
        timestamp: moment(data[0].aifstime_utc.substring(0,8)).toDate(),
        location_name: data[0].name 
    };

    const fields = ["air_temp"];

    fields.forEach(field => {
        result[`${field}_max`] = _.max(data.map(row => row[field])),
        result[`${field}_min`] = _.min(data.map(row => row[field])),
        result[`${field}_avg`] = _.mean(data.map(row => row[field]))
    });

    return result;
}

function downloadWeatherData(url) {
    const options = { url: url, json: true, resolveWithFullResponse: true }
    return rp(options).then((response) => response.body);
}

function writeWeatherDataToDatabase(processedData) {
    const request = sqlConnPool.request()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.input('timestamp', sql.DateTime, processedData.timestamp);
        request.input('location_name', sql.NVarChar, processedData.location_name);
        request.input('air_temp_max', sql.Float, processedData.air_temp_max);
        request.input('air_temp_min', sql.Float, processedData.air_temp_min);
        request.input('air_temp_avg', sql.Float, processedData.air_temp_avg);
        request.query('insert into weather_data (timestamp, location_name, air_temp_max, air_temp_min, air_temp_avg) values (@timestamp, @location_name, @air_temp_max, @air_temp_min, @air_temp_avg)',
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("writeWeatherDataToDatabase: Error occurred: ", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Terry, you are beautiful. That worked a treat. Many thanks kind wizard.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!